# Dice Sum Probabilities and The Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, dice

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html

How does one find the error of a sum of four or five 6-sided dice probability distribution in relation to the Normal Distribution?

Comment: How does one *define* the error of a sum of four or five 6-sided dice probability distribution in relation to the Normal Distribution?

Comment: I don't know; that's part of the problem.

Comment: I found no occurrence of the  word "error" in the reference you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would start by just plotting the exact pdf and the normal approximation, shown for 5 dice, below:

[image: Normal approximation]

Then if you want to examine the errors more closely (defined as the exact value minus the approximation), I would plot those too.

[image: Errors in approximation]

Notice the vertical scale--the errors are fairly small.